# How to dynamically update google map's marker without reloading it

Tags: javascript, html, flask, google-maps-markers

I am getting dynamic latitude and longitude (map_lat, map_lon) from a car, and the value is changing constantly at every 1 second.

Is there any way to update the marker of google maps without reloading the whole map like Uber?
NOTE : WebApp is Flask based.

--[CODE]--

```
var map_lat; // changing value dynamiclly at every 1 sec
var map_lon; // changing value dynamiclly at every 1 sec
.
.
.

setInterval(function myMap() {
        var chlat = window.map_lat;
        var chlon = window.map_lon;

      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(chlat,chlon);
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
      var mapOptions = {
                        center: myCenter,
                        zoom: 18,
                        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});

      marker.setMap(map);
 },2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update only the marker every 1.5 sec :

```
     var chlat = window.map_lat;
     var chlon = window.map_lon;

      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(chlat,chlon);
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
      var mapOptions = {
                        center: myCenter,
                        zoom: 18,
                        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});

      marker.setMap(map);

setInterval( () => {

      marker.setMap(null);


      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(map_lat,map_lon);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});

      marker.setMap(map);


 },1500);
```